I cannot pass the right element to map
I have JSON returned by an API that looks this way:
{
    "Tasks": {
        "TaskItem": [
            {
                "Link": {
                    "Href": "/0",
                    "Rel": "self",
                    "Type": null,
                    "Title": null
                },
                "Uid": 0,
                "Id": 0,
                "Name": "Project Plan v3.0",
                "Start": "2024-03-19T08:00:00",
                "Finish": "2024-10-07T17:00:00",
                "Duration": "48.08:00:00"
            },
            {
                "Link": {
                    "Href": "/1",
                    "Rel": "self",
                    "Type": null,
                    "Title": null
                },
                "Uid": 1,
                "Id": 1,
                "Name": "Prepare",
                "Start": "2024-03-19T08:00:00",
                "Finish": "2024-05-06T17:00:00",
                "Duration": "11.16:00:00"
            },
            {
                "Link": {
                    "Href": "/36",
                    "Rel": "self",
                    "Type": null,
                    "Title": null
                },
                "Uid": 36,
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "Preliminary activities",
                "Start": "2024-03-19T08:00:00",
                "Finish": "2024-04-05T17:00:00",
                "Duration": "4.16:00:00"
            },
        ],
        "link": {
            "Href": "/tasks",
            "Rel": "self",
            "Type": null,
            "Title": null
        }
    },
    "Code": 200,
    "Status": "OK"
}

I am trying to use map to get a new array with only some values from the original array and was trying to use map but I have no luck so far.
My expected result is an array with just Name, Start, Finish and duration of each element.
I tried to do:
let result = tasks.TaskItem.map(getTaskDetail);
console.log(result);

function getTaskDetail(item) {
    return {"Name":item.Name,"Start":item.Start,"Finish":item.Finish,"Duration":item.Duration};
}

but the result is:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tasks.TaskItem.map')


If tasks is that JSON object, you need tasks.Tasks.TaskItem
